# Autocomplete dropdown - add time delay and wait for at least 3 character to be entered

Tags: javascript

I want to create by own autocomplete dropdown in pure javascript and I start from the code below(it is from another answer using jquery),

I want the check not to start immediately, but after a time, an only if the user entered at least 3 characters.

```
 inputString.onkeyup = function() {
            //toUpperCase to make it case insensitive
        var filter = $(this).val().toUpperCase()
        //loop through all the lis 
        for (var i = 0; i < eachStudent.length; i++) {
            //Do this for all the elements (h3, email, joined-details, date)
            var name = $(eachStudent[i]).find('h3').text()
            //display all the results where indexOf() does not return -1
            if (name.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) != -1)
                eachStudent[i].style.display = 'list-item';
            else
                eachStudent[i].style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
```

What if I want to check from the beginning of the text in order, what should I use instead of indexOf() ?

-> indexOf() return the position of occurrence anywhere(for example middle of the string). I want to search only from the beginning of the string to reduce more irrelevant results

Comment: Why replace indexOf? That’s js, all the things starting with a $ in your code seem to be jquery though

Comment: yes, I took code from another answer and try to make in pure javascript. indexOf() return the position of occurrence anywhere(for example middle of the string). I want to search only from the beginning of the string to reduce more irrelevant results

Comment: The short answer is you can use `.startsWith()`. I've provided a working example below, hopefully it helps answer your question. IIRC it's not supported by IE, but I'm sure there's a polyfill out there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.startsWith()`. Based on the snippet you pasted it seems the list to search from is being populated from DOM elements. Here's an example that does that, I've added comments in the JS explaining what's happening:

```js
const input = document.querySelector('input')
const list = document.querySelectorAll('.words li')
const listArray = []

// create array from HTML list
list.forEach(item => {
  // convert to uppercase so we aren't case sensitive
  const searchableItem = item.innerText.toUpperCase()
  listArray.push(searchableItem)
})

// add event listener for search
input.addEventListener('keyup', e => {
  // grab the value of the input field to test against
  // again convert to uppercase so we aren't case sensitive
  let search = e.target.value.toUpperCase()

  // if user has inputted 3 or more characters
  if (search.length > 2) {
    // compare our created listArray with the input value
    let results = listArray.filter(result => result.startsWith(search))

    // show if it's a match otherwise hide
    list.forEach(item => {
      if (item.innerText.toUpperCase().startsWith(search)) {
        item.style.display = 'block'
      } else {
        item.style.display = 'none'
      }
    })
  } else {
    // otherwise hide everything if less than 3 characters are inputted
    list.forEach(item => item.style.display = 'none')
  }
})
```

```css
.words ul li {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<h1>Search an American State</h1>
<div class="container">
  <div class="search">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search state here">
  </div>
  <div class="words">
    <ul>
      <li>Alabama</li>
      <li>Alaska</li>
      <li>Arizona</li>
      <li>Arkansas</li>
      <li>California</li>
      <li>Colorado</li>
      <li>Connecticut</li>
      <li>Delaware</li>
      <li>Florida</li>
      <li>Georgia</li>
      <li>Hawaii</li>
      <li>Idaho</li>
      <li>Illinois</li>
      <li>Indiana</li>
      <li>Iowa</li>
      <li>Kansas</li>
      <li>Kentucky</li>
      <li>Louisiana</li>
      <li>Maine</li>
      <li>Maryland</li>
      <li>Massachusetts</li>
      <li>Michigan</li>
      <li>Minnesota</li>
      <li>Mississippi</li>
      <li>Missouri</li>
      <li>Montana</li>
      <li>Nebraska</li>
      <li>Nevada</li>
      <li>New Hampshire</li>
      <li>New Jersey</li>
      <li>New Mexico</li>
      <li>New York</li>
      <li>North Carolina</li>
      <li>North Dakota</li>
      <li>Ohio</li>
      <li>Oklahoma</li>
      <li>Oregon</li>
      <li>Pennsylvania</li>
      <li>Rhode Island</li>
      <li>South Carolina</li>
      <li>South Dakota</li>
      <li>Tennessee</li>
      <li>Texas</li>
      <li>Utah</li>
      <li>Vermont</li>
      <li>Virginia</li>
      <li>Washington</li>
      <li>West Virginia</li>
      <li>Wisconsin</li>
      <li>Wyoming</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you want the list to be fully visible and filter down from there, remove the line of CSS and replace `none` on line 31 with `block`.